# Shimano clipless pedal screw loosening

Tags: shimano, pedals-clipless

On my MTB I have Shimano M505 clipless pedals and one of the pedal bases has play. The screws that keep the front piece attached to the pedal base regularly loosen irrespective of how much I try to tighten them.

Any suggestions on how to fix the pedal?

Comment: Could you post a photo please, ideally marked up to show what moves and shouldn't?  At the very least a model number would be a good idea.  I've got M520 and M424, and can interpret your question very differently depending on which one I picture

Comment: Go to a hardware store and get some ["blue" thread lock compound](https://www.loctiteproducts.com/en/products/specialty-products/specialty/loctite_threadlockerblue242.html).

Comment: Red threadlock may be even better, it’s not like you plan on removing the thing anyways.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments about using a blue thread locker (or red if you plan to never remove them), I would wonder if a different material of machine screw might have more friction in the threads as well.  Stainless steel may have had threads cut too smooth to provide enough grip.  Additionally, if it is a flathead or philips type screw head you will not be able to put much force on it, even with both hands turning a screwdriver.  Using a hex head or star head with a ratchet can get magnitudes more torque, just don't strip the threads.

PS:  I now realized with the idea that stripping the screw from overtightening could happen on a new screw could still apply to the old screw.  If you've really tightened it with all you've got its likely that the threads have been pulled out and your screws are now more like toothpicks.

Comment: I don’t think you really need to get a different screw. There’s probably millions of pedals out there holding fine with the stock screws, so all that’s needed is a little threadlock I think. Stripping the screws is a real possibility.